# creating a folder in contacts app of my iPhone

Tags: ios, contacts

I need to create a folder or a category in my contacts of iPhone. In my app i am providing a functionality where a user can save a contact that he receives from a web service directly to his contacts under a folder "XYZ". I have searched and searched, but couldnot find a proper solution. please help..

Comment: Check the documentation for the ABGroup object and the ABUIGroups sample project. It shows how to create, edit and delete groups and assign contacts to them.

Comment: ok thanks.. i will get back with the results after some time..